# Qt - Resize layout when adding items

Tags: c++, qt

I have a vertical layout I'm filling with file names.
I have a QFileDialog to select files, then the slot is adding names to the layout.

```
void convertInterface::on_browseButton_clicked()
{
    fileNames = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(this, tr("Open File"), "./FilesToConvert", tr("Test Files (*.txt)"));
    for each (QString item in fileNames)
    {
        QLabel *name = new QLabel(this);
        name->setText(QFileInfo(item).fileName());
        ui.mainLayout->addWidget(name);
     }
 }
```

The result with 3 files :

[image]

The result with 3 more files, so 6 total :

[image]

Overall layout :

[image]

How to resize the layout automatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, instead of adding the `QVBoxLayout` as a child widget to the `groupBox` widget, set the `groupBox`'s layout directly. Just right-click on the `groupBox` line in the Object Inspector and in the menu select *Lay out* - *[something]*. This option might not be available if the widget has no childs - as a workaround, just add a dummy widget, set the layout and delete the dummy widget.

Second, you need some kind of automatic layout on the parent widget as well, so do the same with `centralWidget`. Than `groupBox` will expand automatically as needed.

If you break the layout of the parent (`centralWidget`), the size of the child widgets is fixed and cannot update automatically.

Comment: My vertical layout is in a groupbox which is in the central layout. How should I do it ?

Comment: The hierarchy is not fully clear from your question, can you add it there? E.g. a screenshot of Object Inspector (if you develop in a QtCreator/Designer) would say a lot. Or specify as text.

Comment: I've added a picture

Comment: Ok, I have selected my groupbox and just clicked on Vertical Layout, previously the groupbox was put in a widget and now it is put in a VLayout even though it doesnt appear in the inspector. It works, thanks for the help